# I need to get a JSON array of objects into an Angular page via GET request from API controller

Tags: angular

The HTML Portion

```
<div *ngIf="list">
 <ul>
  <li *ngFor="let td of list">
   {{td.Title}}
   {{td.Description}}
   {{td.Date}}
   {{td.Url}}
   {{td.Tag}}
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

The component portion

```
list: any = [];

constructor(private service: TradeDetailService) { }

ngOnInit() {
 this.service.getAllTrades()
  .subscribe(data => {

    this.list = data;
    console.log(data);
  })
}
```

The service class portion

```
getAllTrades(): Observable<TradeDetail> {
 return this.http.get<TradeDetail>(this.rootUrl + '/Trade');
}
```

The model portion:

```
export class TradeDetail {
 Id: number;
 UserId: string;
 Title: string;
 Description: string;
 Date: Date;
 Url: string;
 FairnessRating: number;
 TrustRating: number;
 Tag: string;
}
```

Here is the result I am currently getting:

[Current results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFVlV.jpg)

and here is my data that I am receiving every time i send a GET request to that particular controller:

Also pretend the object shown is really 6 objects hence why there are 6 dots

```
[
 {
    "id": 2,
    "userId": "b9fc2043-ce83-426c-8e2c-063e40a26271",
    "title": "Trade 1",
    "description": "good trade",
    "date": "2016-09-09T00:00:00-05:00",
    "url": "https://devimagegallery1.blob.core.windows.net/images/cir_animacion_1.jpg",
    "fairnessRating": 23,
    "trustRating": 99,
    "tag": "#tree"
}
]
```

My issue is that I feel the data is getting read and actually being put on the array but for some reason it wont show the appropriate parameters. I think it has to do how I am unsuccessfully formatting the incoming JSON array objects and not initializing them based on their attributes.

Comment: Maybe not a problem: you mixed upper- and lowercase property names (e.g. `userId` vs. `UserId`) .

Comment: Is GET API returning array of one object or array of six objects?

Comment: GET is returning 6 objects but the data would have been too long to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you try the following html to see exactly what the object in each row contains:

```
<div *ngIf="list">
 <ul>
  <li *ngFor="let td of list">
   {{td | json}}
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

The JSON Pipe prints the given object as a json and is quite handy when debugging loops.

Then you should see what your td object contains for every row and continue setting the title etc. with the exact variable names.

Comment: It work!!!!! I at least can now see the json data and must now suffer through formatting it correctly. Thanks